# iPad Safari-like zooming in and out thumbnails view

Tags: xcode, ipad, uikit, ios

First of all, I have plenty of experience on iOS development but I am not so keen on Core Animation. I would like to reproduce the effect in Safari (both iPhone and iPad) when the page you're viewing at shrinks itself and 'zooms out' into a thumbnail view, and after you select a given thumbnail, it then 'zooms in' and the corresponding page is restored.

What is the best way to accomplish this? I would apply it to a reguiar UIView subclass - not a UIWebView - but I am not so sure on how to do the whole shrinking effect, and specifying the destination frame for the zoomed out thumbnail (suppose I have lots of thumbnails in the screen and I would like to position the current view into a particular thumbnail).

Best,

Answer (score 2):

It's likely to be a simple CoreAnimation effect, adjusting the view transform rather than the frame. That should work on any sort of view. I'm optimistic that you're lack of keenness is unfamiliarity rather than an actual dislike, so I'll press on with the CoreAnimation answer in case it is helpful...

UIView has a really great convenience method for setting up animations. For example, to do an animated shrink of the view to half the size, leaving it centred on the same location:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5f, 0.5f);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

To shrink it and shift its centre 50 pixels to the right:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
view.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5f, 0.5f), 50.0f, 0.0f);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

And to return it to normal from either state:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
webView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The theory behind it is that some properties of views are animatable. Those are properties that CoreAnimation is able to adjust as part of an ongoing animation all on its own. the UIView class methods beginAnimations:context: and commitAnimations set up and then begin a CoreAnimation block. Essentially, every change that you make to an an animatable property after beginAnimations:context: doesn't take effect immediately but is set up to be the target state of an animation. When you perform commitAnimations, the animation occurs.

There are a bunch of other controls you can use to adjust animations through the UIView convenience methods, all described in the UIView documentation.

If you weren't to use CoreAnimation then you'll have to do the frame-by-frame adjustment of the transform yourself, though I really don't see any benefit to that approach — it'll cost you more in CPU terms and is unlikely to be anywhere near as smooth.

Definitely stick to the transform rather than adjusting the frame if you can; adjusting the transform changes how a view is added to the screen. It doesn't cause the view itself to redraw. So if you change the scale, that's just like zooming an image of the view. If you change the frame or bounds then iOS will discard its current buffer of how the view looks and request a redraw, which costs a lot more. Worse still, if you have anything sitting on a CATiledLayer (such as a map view or a web view) then the view will turn into its background colour and probably not fade in again until after the animation is finished. Similarly, any view that decides how to draw based on frame size won't appear to scale but just to change size.

Comment: Hi Tommy, thanks for your detailed response. I've been using UIView animations to do some basic stuff, along with CATransition, and that's where my experience with CoreAnimation ends. What I've never touched though is the view transform property, mostly because I haven't had the chance to really understand it. But based on what you suggest, it doesn't looks that complicated and seems to be the way to do what I'm looking for. Now what about the transitioning to and from the thumbnail view? Could I in the same animation block add it as a subview, with an initial alpha value of 0 and increase it?

Comment: Adding as a subview takes effect immediately whether inside or outside of an animation block, but alpha is an animatable property so it should be safe to add it with an alpha of 0 then set the alpha to 1 inside a block for a smooth transition.